How to avoid arithmetic operations from appearing on the numeric keypad of tablets in Flutter?
Inside the TextFormField I am using the following to display a numeric keypad and only allow digits without decimals:
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal:false),
inputFormatters: [
               FilteredTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
               FilteredTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
               ]

On mobile phones this works very well, however I am testing on a 10-inch Android tablet and I see the numeric keypad on the right side and an arithmetic operations keyboard on the left side that becomes useless and inconvenient.

How can I make only the numeric keypad show?
